# 404 with routes that dont come from the NavMenu

Tags: c#, parameters, routes, blazor

I have a site with routing to various blazor component pages that all work fine when on my local machine. However after deploying to iis some of the them no longer work.

```
/
/request
```

However routes with parameters all fail with a 4040

```
/request/1
/edit/1
```

Can anyone help? I dont even know where to start looking.

**Update:**
So my inital assumption was wrong. Its not the format of the route that is the problem its something else, which I suspect is simple to fix. And most of you will groan at how special I'm being.

Its A Blazor Server hosted app.

**StartUp**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using PartCreation.Data;
using PartCreation.Interfaces;
using PartCreation.Models;
using PartCreation.Repositorys;

namespace PartCreation
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var emailConfig = Configuration
       .GetSection("EmailConfiguration")
       .Get<EmailConfiguration>();
            services.AddSingleton(emailConfig);

            services.AddHttpClient("HttpClientWithSSLUntrusted").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
            {
                ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                return true;
            }
            });

            services.AddScoped<IEmail, EmailSenderRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IBrands, BrandsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUom, UomRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ISuppliers, SupplierRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IPartClass, PartClassRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IPartCreation, PartCreationRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IEpicor, EpicorRepository>();
            services.AddAutoMapper(new[] { typeof(AutomapperProfiles).Assembly });

            services.AddDbContext<ErpDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(
                   Configuration.GetConnectionString("ErpConnection")));

            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(
               Configuration.GetConnectionString("RequestsConnection")));

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Links from the Nav menu work, but links from pages do not.

```
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">PartCreation</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">

        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="request">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span>New Request
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="requests/me" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> My Requests
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Requests
            </NavLink>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

All the link from the above code work and resolve the links as

- http://servername/partcreation/request
- http://servername/partcreation/requests/me

```
@page "/"
@page "/requests"

@inject IPartCreation _requests

<div class="m-auto" style="width:90%;">
    <table class="table table-striped w-100">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Priority</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Part number</th>                           
                <th>Requester</th>
                <th>Requested</th>
                <th>Comment</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Requests != null)
            {
                @foreach (var item in Requests)
                {
            <tr>
                @if (IsAdmin)
                {
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="request/@item.Id">Edit</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="requests/me">View</a>
                </td>
                }
                else
                {
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/request/me">View</a>
              
            </td>
                }

                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Priorty</td>
                <td>@item.Status</td>
                <td>@item.Partnumber</td>
                <td>@item.Requester</td>
                <td>@item.Requested</td>
                <td>@item.Comments</td>
            </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <Pagination CurrentPage="@paginationDTO.Page" TotalAmountPages="totalAmountPages" Radius="1"
                SelectedPage="SelectedPage" />
</div>





@code {

    List<RequestListDto> Requests;
    PaginationDto paginationDTO = new PaginationDto() { RecordsPerPage = 10 };
    private int totalAmountPages;
    bool IsAdmin = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Admincheck();
        await LoadRequests();
    }


    async Task Admincheck()
    {
        IsAdmin = await _requests.IsAdmin(Environment.UserName);
        
    }

    private async Task LoadRequests()
    {


        var paginatedResponse = await _requests.GetRequest(paginationDTO);
        Requests = paginatedResponse.Response;
        totalAmountPages = paginatedResponse.TotalAmountPages;



    }


    private async Task SelectedPage(int page)
    {
        paginationDTO.Page = page;
        await LoadRequests();
    }
}
```

The link from the above code work when I use visual studio and and IIS express/
But when I deploy to server Deafult Website >> Part Creation the above links do not work and they resolve to

- servername/request/me
- servername/requests

So the miss out the "partcreation" section for some reason.

if it makes a difference the Navmenu is in the default Shared folder and the other page is inthe default Pages folder

Comment: Blazor Server, Web Assembly stand-alone, or ASP.NET hosted Web Assembly? Could you show your Program and StartUp class code, and also the page routes.

Comment: On a IIS server uses have limited access to resource on server.  You connect as a GUEST. So I suspect the routes that are failing are trying to use resources on server that GUEST do not have the credentials to access.  Http error 404 indicates URL is not found.

Comment: @PeterMorris Hi Thanks for the response. Ive updated the question. Its a different issue that I first thought and I suspect a lot simpler to fix, I just dont know. I've not had this issue when I deployed before. I've added the NavMenu page where the hrefs work, and a page where the hrefs dont work. To me they seem the same.

Comment: page "/requests" would only work without a parameter. 
page "/requests"
page "/requests/{id}"     You need both defined

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-parameters

Comment: @Orak sorry  i didnt post all my page routes. Ti do have  page "/requests/me" and  page "/requests/{id:int}" on other pages. And they do work on local host, just not when deployed

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I'm going close this question. Having made no changes to the code, but redployed it a fewntimes. This is now working as expected. I'm assured there were no changes made on the server. So either there was an issue with deployment or there were server changes.